# Gnome shell suspend/resume oddity

Tags: gnome-shell, thunderbird, gdm, 19.04

I have noticed a recect oddity (within the last week) in behavior of my Gnome-shell upon resume:

If I have a window (Thunderbird) open, and suspend by closing lid all seems to go as it should.

When I open the lid and resume, I see my Thunderbird window, but cannot input anything to the window.  If I press alt-tab, then Thunderbird pops open, as if I am switching to that task, and accepts input again.

I notice this most often with Thunderbird, but only because that is most often open.

Has anyone else noted this behaviour?

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 chick chick 4096 Apr 25 07:26 .
drwx------ 3 chick chick 4096 May  1 13:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 chick chick 4096 Apr 24 19:06 appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 chick chick 4096 Apr 15 07:52 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
```

Comment: Are you using workspaces?

Comment: @heynnema They are enabled, but I rarely use them.  This only started about a week ago, but I was not smart enough to look for what updates may be involved.

Comment: I saw something on one of the machines that I upgraded, that has some remote similarity to your symptom, but there's many factors involved. Try this... when TB won't let you type in its window, switch workspaces by keyboard shortcut, or via GUI, and see if the TB window will now take input.

Comment: @heynnema I'll give it a shot next time it happens.  I've gotten pretty accustomed to hitting alt-tab which does bring the window back.

Comment: You can obviously test just by suspend/resuming :-) You don't have to wait.

Comment: Show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema Added.  Currently only operating extension is dash-to-dock, the other is 'off'...

Comment: One machine I upgraded to 19.04 had a number of incompatible GNOME extensions, and DTD was one of them. You might disable, AND temporarily move it out of the extensions folder, restart GNOME shell, and see if your problem still exists.

Comment: See user comments at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Comment: @heynnema The problem did not recur since I disabled the `KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support ` - I am going to assume that was the cause, test for a while more, and bemoan the lack of a systray...

Comment: If you disabled one of the two standard 19.04 GNOME extensions, I don't think that's it. As I mentioned, and as other users have noted in the link that I gave you, DTD is probably a good culprit. Change it around, as per my previous suggestion, reinstall appindicator, and retest. Report back so I can put together an answer for you.

Comment: @heynnema I'll try removing the Ubuntu dock extension - I am using the Gnome interface rather than the Ubuntu interface, and I don't think that `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` is active, but you never know.

Comment: That's NOT what I was recommending. LEAVE the two standard extensions, but turned off, and REMOVE DTD... not just turn it off... remove it and then restart GNOME shell. You asked the question. I've given you a couple of ideas. But I get the impression that you haven't done any of them... am I wrong?

Comment: @heynnema I'm sorry to give you the impression I was not following the directions - I do sometimes get confused.  As of now, I've removed DTD, and do have `appindicator support` as the only installed and active extension

Comment: Go ahead and reinstall the standard Ubuntu dock extension (and the standard Ubuntu appindicator) also. It's normally turned off, as is the appindicator. Did you restart GNOME Shell?

Comment: @heynnema Actually I rebooted, and have not observed the behavour yet - I have some outside activities to take care of, and will put the computer to sleep to see if it happens.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry about not getting back to you.  Yes, the problem seems to be connected to Dash-to-dock.  It's troublesome saying that, because  it is not a consistent problem, and comes and goes according to some schedule I have not discerned.  With DtD removed, I have not seen an occurence of the problem, so if you would write up an answer...?

Comment: Charles... done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04, many users are having difficulties related to GNOME extensions that were working fine in earlier versions of Ubuntu.

If you go to [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/), you can see what extensions you have installed. Severe GNOME extension compatibility issues may not permit viewing installed extensions this way, without causing a lockup or crash. Another way to view installed extensions is to use `gnome-tweaks`, otherwise known as `Tweaks`.

Worst case scenarios involve having to boot into Recovery mode, and manually removing GNOME extensions from `/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

In this particular case, `Dash to Dock` was causing problems. After it's physical removal, the system is running fine now. User reports about its 19.04 compatibility can be see [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/).